# Sitecore: Show input option after using menu context item

Tags: asp.net, input, sitecore, user-input, sitecore8

I've added a menu context item to the TreelistEx. This menu item sends a messages that I later catch in a HandleMessage method.

In this method i create a new item ( template type and parent item are given in the source of the treelist field ).

All i need now is a way to ask the user for a name. But i haven't been able to find a simple way to do this.

[image]

```
class MyTreeListEx : TreelistEx, IMessageHandler
{
    void IMessageHandler.HandleMessage(Message message)
    {
        if (message == null)
        { return; }

        if (message["id"] == null)
        { return; }

        if (!message["id"].Equals(ID))
        { return; }

        switch (message.Name)
        {
            case "treelist:edit":
                // call default treelist code

            case "mytreelistex:add":
                // my own code to create a new item
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Edit: added image & code + i'm using Sitecore 8 Update 1

Comment: Can you add your code to give your question some context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which version of Sitecore you use but what you can try is `SheerResponse.Input` method.

You can use it like this:

```cs
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Globalization;
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.FieldTypes;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;

void IMessageHandler.HandleMessage(Message message)
{
    ...
    case "mytreelistex:add":
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "AddItem");
        break;
}

protected static void AddItem(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!args.HasResult)
            return;
        string newItemName = args.Result;
        // create new item here

        // if you need refresh the page:
        //SheerResponse.Eval("scForm.browser.getParentWindow(scForm.browser.getFrameElement(window).ownerDocument).location.reload(true)");
    }
    else
    {
        SheerResponse.Input("Enter the name of the new item:", "New Item Default Name", Settings.ItemNameValidation, 
            Translate.Text("'$Input' is not a valid name."), Settings.MaxItemNameLength);
        args.WaitForPostBack();
    }
}
```

This code will even validate your new item name for incorrect characters and length.

Comment: My class is a standard class on the server. So the sheer textbox isn't renderd before all the code has been executed.

Comment: yep a round trip is needed, a example is the Google Map Field, https://bitbucket.org/ndoeyaditya/sitecore-gmap-location-picker-field/src/6037878354ba374a8903faf0a1ae247a0440a007/MyApp.SitecoreCustom/GMapField/GoogleMapField.cs?at=master The SheerResponse is working in Sitecore 8,

Comment: Thank you Marek Musielak! This is exactly what i need.